# Insert a file in TextBox in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textbox, textarea

I have an "Agree And Conditions file ( rtf document )" and/or a "disclaimer file" to add to a textBox or Text Area that I would like to add to my MVC3 web app.
I don't know how to do that. I have google searched but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should avoid text boxes and just show the content in a `<div>` with a **fixed** `height` and vertical scroll.

Then just add a `<input type="checkbox">` to force the user say it agreed with the statement.

You can always have that `checkbox` that could be disabled while the user did not scroll down the div... I don't like it but it appears over and over in several websites.

Comment: I agree, but just to add markup: `<div style="height:400px, width:400px;overflow:auto">Your Conditions Here ...</div>`

Comment: Thank you very much balexandre